# Virtual box running android studio virtual device needs vtx

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, ubuntu-18.04, android-studio

I am having a windows machine as base(main/default) OS and using virtual box on top of it to run Ubuntu 18.04. On this linux machine(running via virtualbox on windows base machine) I am running android studio. The problem is when I try to run a virtual device(to emulate my app development) on android studio it throws an error as Vt-x required (Shown in the image) Now I have vt-x running (as per the configs in VirtualBox settings) and want to fix this.

IMO virtualbox is an emulator itself and cant power another emulator I guess or something on this line. Not sure shot in dark.

P.s: It works fine with AS on my windows without virtual box.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37ukt.png)

Comment: What CPU is your system running on?

Comment: Intel i7-7700HQ CPU. As mentioned, I am having this issue with AS on ubuntu on virtualbox. On my main Windows OS the AVD works.

Comment: That's not clear in the question. You say you're running VB AND AS, not AS ON VB. Please edit your question to make this more clear. As a note your PS repeats this unclear phrasing. The computer has VB on it: saying "Windows without VB" does not appear to accurately convey the state of things.

Comment: This is my first ever question. Sorry for the inconvenience, I have edited the question. Is it understandable now? Thanks : )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  Any information should be contained in the question body instead of a comment

Comment: “The problem is when I try to run a virtual device ” - correct terminology is important by virtual devices do you mean a virtual machine?

Answer (score 7):

VirtualBox didn't support nested VMs until version 6 and this is only currently supported with AMD CPUs.  Intel CPUs do not support nested virtualization on VirtualBox.

> **VirtualBox Documentation**: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nested-virt
>
> Oracle VM VirtualBox supports *nested virtualization* on host systems that run AMD CPUs.

Comment: Oh! Yeah, I am running an Intel CPU. So my guess was right it was something with nested virtualization. Any way to fix it with current hardware constraints?

Comment: @Manthan_Admane - No;  Nested virtualization isn’t supported by VirtualBox on Intel systems

Comment: No, hardware constraints are typically not possible to be worked around.

Comment: **Note that this is no longer true** support for newer (5th gen+ i5+) Intel processors was added in 6.1

Answer (score 3):

Recently VirtualBox released a new beta which includes:
"Support for nested hardware-virtualization on Intel CPUs (starting with 5th generation Core i, codename Broadwell)"

You can find it here:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=94724

Comment: Official v6.1.0: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.1#v0 - same as in this answer + "so far tested only with guest running VirtualBox"

Comment: Ok so I tested with  8th generation Intel Core i5 & VB 6.1.26 and the *option was disabled*, **however** I found out it can still be turned on manually in terminal with `VBoxManage modifyvm NAME_OF_MACHINE --nested-hw-virt on`

Comment: When I finally ran the device from Android Studio Device Manager, I got a funny message: *"Emulator is running using nested virtualization. This is not recommended. It may not work at all. And typically the performance is not quite good."* ...yea and a black screen and 300seconds timeout x) will get back if I get it working ...

Comment: After many hours of waiting, I gave up.